# AJAX response is empty when I try to access any of its properties

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I'm trying to pull in some JSON data via AJAX for a Greasemonkey script.

Here's what I have:

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var xmlresult = JSON.parse(this.response);
    // this works
    console.log(xmlresult);
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mledoze/countries/master/countries.json", true);
xmlhttp.send();

// this doesn't work
console.log(xmlresult);
```

For some reason, `xmlresult` is always empty. If I dump out the response in the console directly, there's clearly data in the response, but if I try to do anything with it outside of my if block, it doesn't exist.

Comment: `[...], but if I try to do anything with it outside of my if block[...]` where outside of the `if` block do you try to access it? If it is outside of the callback then it won't be populated because the request is async. Show a full minimal example the illustrates where it is empty when you try to access it.

Comment: like you can see I added a console.log to your snippet and it works (shows the json)

Comment: I was trying to access the result outside that block of code, after `xmlhttp.send()` without any luck.

Comment: This is not an AJAX issue. The question lacks a basic understanding of scope.

Answer (score -1):

That is because `xmlresult` is a local variable in the `onreadystatechange` listener function and it's value won't be kept for outside use. You should do:

```
var xmlresult;
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    xmlresult = JSON.parse(this.response);
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mledoze/countries/master/countries.json", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: Yes, it needs to be global or at least to be outside of the scope of the listener function, depending on where it's value is needed.

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's global, when the method is **asynchronous**?

Comment: this is async, your best bet is to pass a callback that fires once the response data is received. or look into promises

Comment: It does matter if the method is asynchronous, because the `xmlresult` variable will get a value only at a latter time when the async function is complete. Usually, you can isolate the moment by making a function call with what you need to do in the async function body.

Comment: You are missing something. In the original post, the variable IS defined inside the function scope with the `var` keyword, so it won't be visible outside at all. But I have changed that in my answer to show the right way to do it.

Comment: @CatalinIancu - I added a function inside the onreadystatechange IF block passing the parsed JSON result, and that seems to have addressed my problem. Thank you!

Also - I tried defining the variable outside the block, but it was still null.